# Why is there an error when I try to run this code using command line arguments in shell?

Tags: c, shell, argv, roman-numerals, argc

I have a code called `main.c` that attempts to convert roman numerals into integers, and my code has to run via command line inputs, here is the code by the way:

and I would like to know what is the simplest way to solve this issue.

**P.S.** Yes, I know that the roman code that I provided is incomplete and doesn't cover many cases, I'll edit that, right now I just want to know why my code doesn't have an output

Comment: It's a good idea to print error messages, to make problems more obvious. So instead of `if (argc != 2) { return 1; }` it would be `if (argc != 2) { printf("Usage: %s number\n", argv[0]); return 1; }`

Comment: Why have you edited your question and eliminated all the code? Do you think your problem will not be helpful to other people?  Please edit your question and leave it as it was before you erased the code, or erase it completely, but please, don't destroy the way it has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

Your usage is wrong. The way you are calling your program feeds STDIN to the program that you never read.

You should use `./roman XVII`